# update TEdit text from combobox

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, replace

I have a form that consist of two `TComboBox` and one `TEdit` controls and I would like to be able to update a word in the `TEdit` control with the value from the comboboxes, but not quite sure how to make it work.

Example:

Combobox #1 has the following items: `sue, bill, andy, chris`

Combobox #2 has the following items: `1, 2, 3`

The `TEdit` control starts out looking something like this: `andy has 3 cars`

Now, what I want to do is to be able to change the word `andy` with the currently selected item in combobox #1 and the number `3` with the currently selected item in combobox #2, but I just cannot seem to wrap my head around how to accomplish this and thought I would come to the experts for a little advise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assign the same event hander to both combo boxes' `OnChange` event:

```
procedure TForm1.ComboBox1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Edit1.Text := ComboBox1.Text + ' has ' + ComboBox2.Text + ' car(s)';
end;
```

If the '... has ... car(s)' is not a fixed string, you do not have a well-defined problem. The simplest approach that will yield a well-defined problem and a solution is to add a second `TEdit` control. Now, let the two comboboxes and the first edit control share the same `OnChange` event:

```
procedure TForm1.ComboBox1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Edit2.Text := Format(Edit1.Text, [ComboBox1.Text, ComboBox2.Text]);
end;
```

Now the user can enter, for example, `%s has %s car(s).` in the first edit box.

However, if you *know* that the string entered by the user in the edit box will contain exactly one item from each combobox, and that no other part of the string coincides with a combobox item, then, of course, you can dynamically replace the item in the edit box. Then let the comboboxes share this event:

```
procedure TForm1.ComboBox1Change(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to ComboBox1.Items.Count - 1 do
    if Pos(ComboBox1.Items[i], Edit1.Text) > 0 then
    begin
      Edit1.Text := StringReplace(Edit1.Text, ComboBox1.Items[i],
        ComboBox1.Text, [rfReplaceAll]);
      break;
    end;
  for i := 0 to ComboBox2.Items.Count - 1 do
    if Pos(ComboBox2.Items[i], Edit1.Text) > 0 then
    begin
      Edit1.Text := StringReplace(Edit1.Text, ComboBox2.Items[i],
        ComboBox2.Text, [rfReplaceAll]);
      break;
    end;
end;
```

To try this, set the comboboxes to `Sue` and `2`, and write `Sue and I have 3 cats. Sue is cute.`. Now try to change the comboboxes!

You can make this more robust by only replacing the *old* combobox text with the new one. To accomplish this, you need to save the previous value in the combobox. At any rate, you cannot, even in theory, make this completely robust. Indeed, what if the string is 'Bill called 911 when he got a heart attack paying his electric bill 5 days ago.' This string might very well end up as 'Sue called 26 when he got a heart attack paying his electric Sue 26 days ago.'

More subtly, if one of the combobox items is 'car' and another is 'train', then 'carnage' might be transformed to 'trainnage'.

Comment: The problem with that is that the text in the edit control is editable by the end user so there would be no way to hard code the placement of the combo box in the string.

Comment: @GDF, the edit appears to be modifiable for a reason; if it wasn't, there would be no need to use an edit - a label would work.

Comment: I know how to make it readonly, but the point is the end user NEEDS to be able to edit the string manually. The example above was just that, an example. In the real application there will be about 50 or so of these combo boxes which will be used to set the values for a console application. A Frontend if you will.

Comment: Thx Andreas, I believe the 2nd solution will work. I just needed a push in the right direction.